# Ansible - not able to find .bash_profile file when I'm using the following code

Tags: linux, ansible, bash

```
- name: restarting .bash_profile
  command: chdir=/home/ec2-user/ source .bash_profile
```

I'm trying to use source command for .bash_profile file, but it's throwing an error:

> {"changed": false, "cmd": "source .bash_profile", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}

But the file exists in the given path. Is there any way that I can run that command for `.bash_profile` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` is not an external command which you could run on its own, so you cannot use `command` module ("*No such file or directory*" error refers to the `source`, not `.bash_profile`).

It is a Bash builtin, so you could use `shell` module to execute it, but the real problem is that it will have no effect on other tasks, which I believe is what you aim for.

What you can do, is to prepend the other command, which you probably want to run after sourcing a new environment, for example:

```
- shell: source .bash_profile && my_command
  args:
    chdir: /home/ec2-user/
    executable: /bin/bash
```